# Trying to call and bind image in img src tag from server in mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Hi i'm trying to bind image in img tag in mvc .this tag is used in asp.net like this in the same way i want to bind image in MVC/
eg
ASP.net

```
<img alt="User Image" width="80px" height="80px" class="img img-thumbnail" src='<%="http://196.0.2.201/p001.ashx?pf=YY&cid="+Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID] %>'/>
```

in mvc

I want to pass `@ViewBag.session` as parameter instead of `Session[CommonConstants.SESSION_USER_ID]` how to achieve it in Mvc any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVC why not base64 the image on the server while the page is being constructed and embed that in the image src for example with Razor:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @Model.Base64Image">
```

This way any logic used for generating the image is part of the same controller logic that is building your page.
Step by step:
your razor page will have a @model ViewModel Directive at the top and an image element somewhere that you are populating as above, the jpeg part can be any image type must must match the type that is being encoded.
your view model should have a string property in this case called Base64Image.
your controller should have a part that gets and converts the image e.g.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new ViewModel();

            // important thing here is to convert the image into a byte array:
            var imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"image.jpeg");
            // Convert byte array to Base64 String
            model.Base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

            // return View model with base64 encoded image to page
            return View(model);
        }
```

the rendered page at the client side will have an image element something like this.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, TWFuIGlzIGRpc3RpbmdR== ">
```

the base64 encoding will be hundreds of characters long.
Doing it this way the client doesn't need to make a second call to get the image its already in the page. What you're trying to do is define an endpoint that the client will call on to get the image.

Comment: i am trying like this inside img tag please correct if you have any idea src="@Url.Content("'http://192.0.1.201/p001.ashx?pf=YY&cid='"+ ViewBag.session)"

Comment: I've extended my answer with more implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

- Declare a new model

  `public class ModelImg
      {
          public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
          public bool MyProperty2 { get; set; }
          public string Img { get; set; }
      }`
- use your object in controller :

`ModelImg model = new ModelImg(){Img = @"MyImgAsString",MyProperty1 = 1,MyProperty2 = true};`

- Assign your object or your img directly to a ViewData in your controller view:

  `ViewData["Img"] = model.Img;`

In your View assign your src :

```
<img alt="User Image" width="80px" height="80px" class="img img-thumbnail" src='ViewData["Img"]'/>
```